# Modeling subdivided pipes

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, bezier-curves

i started to try modeling some pipes, but i'm stucked about subdividing them (the base pipes) as the pictures shown down.

[image: metro plastic pipes]
[image: modeling start]

i tried with adding a cylinder, then with a bezier curve then bevel by a circle, any ideas

Comment: I would model it with a cylinder, only one though. Just push the verts where you want the small pipes to appear down. Possibly by using proportional editing.

Answer (score 2):

you want the pipe to branch off into the many pipes? I would try Boolean (union) a cluster of solid pipes (I used subdivided cubes) . Make sure the verts are aligned before you union. Delete the unwanted faces  then select the verts on one end and use the circle command to round them out. extrude then use the spin tool to add the elbow. apply subdivide to taste.
steps from right to left.

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply, so i tried your method and it seems a good approach, i did a quick screens,  i don't make often screencast often, so sorry for the quality (used blender for that ;-) ) [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d6d4rM_39E&feature=youtu.be]